# Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I've developed a plugin for Dynamics CRM 2011 on-premises using developers toolkit. I've not updated the default code and simply deployed it. But I receive exception. I don't what is the problem with it. Following is the Exception Details.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: STGDevPlugin.Plugins.PreValidateAccountCreateDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: STGDevPlugin.Plugins.PreValidateAccountCreate</Message>
  <Timestamp>2015-08-03T10:43:33.5989514Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[STGDevPlugin.Plugins: STGDevPlugin.Plugins.PreValidateAccountCreate]
[7122c821-cc39-e511-8aa3-005056b04acd: PreValidateAccountCreate]


</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you verify that you have the same DLL version of

> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk and Microsoft.Crm.Sdk

included in your GAC?

You probably have 5.0.0.0 in your GAC and 6.0.0.0 in your solution or the other way around.

Comment: I've same version `6.0.0.0`

Comment: Issue is resolved by deleting Microsoft.Xrm.sdk and adding again into the references of solutions.

Comment: Great, have fun coding